# Find functions $g(x)$ and $f(x)$ such that $\lim_{x\to 7} f(x)$= 0 but $\lim_{x\to 7} [f(x) g(x)]$ is not $0$

Tags: calculus, limits

find function f and g such that
$\lim_{x\to 7} f(x)= 0$ but $\lim_{x\to 7} [f(x)  g(x)]$ is not 0

my initial thought is that $f(x) = x - 7$ and $g(x) = \frac{1}{x-7}$.

`

Comment: And what is wrong with your initial thought?

Comment: except for parentheses and possibly the need to specify the domain of $g4 or  define $g(7)$ separately

Comment: i was not sure about my initial thought

Answer (score 1):

The initial thought is correct.

Comment: thanks a lot, i was not sure about my answer